# About the reusable html controls together with javascript code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I am working on a page with 2 groups of HTML controls almost same. I am wondering is there anyway that I can reuse it rather than duplicate both HTML and JavaScript code.

I was trying to put it on a partial view but later on I found the JavaScript code can't be reused since the IDs are actually referring to the first group of HTML controls.

How to solve this in general? Thanks!

Comment: We need a little more info.  Why are your ids different?  Post an example of both html fragments and the javascript accessing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented it as a jQuery plug-in is a good idea.